# How to assign an arbitrary value to a variable when user clicks submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, forms

A submit button allows to send it's `name` and `value` attributes along with the rest of request, when it is clicked, allowing to remember which one of submit buttons was used to send the form data. However, the value sent must be the same text that is displayed on the button. Is there any way for a submit button to send an arbitrary value instead of button text, preferably the way that does not rely on user having JavaScript enabled? Also, is the answer to this question somehow different for XHTML and HTML5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `button` instead of an `input`:

```
<button id="butter" type="submit" value="go">Let's do it</button>​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/duySv/

That way the label and value are separate.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/button

Answer (score 1):

Try using a button element.

```
<form method="post">
    <button name="abutton" value="abc">foo</button>
</form>​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/54DfJ/